# Java substr to check and activate after typing at least 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

How do i use substr to activate after at least 2 numbers are typed into the field.

```
if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
```

Its a W3 thing for autocomplite your from, but it starts showing allready with 1 letter, and thats too soon.

i tried with `val.length>`

but with no luck

The w3 link itself is here
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

Comment: "java" !== "javascript" !

Comment: In java, you use String#equals() to compare strings rather than ==.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `val` length, change

```
closeAllLists();
if (!val) { return false;}
```

with

```
closeAllLists();
if (!val || val.length < 2) { return false;}
```